# Ruby on Rails - Thinking Sphinx Problem

Tags: ruby, thinking-sphinx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem running Thinking Sphinx with Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715621/problem-running-thinking-sphinx-with-rails-2-3-5)

I'm running rails 2.3.5
Every time I run rake ts:start or ts.rebuild the rake file quite with the following:

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name

rake aborted!
key not found
```

I have Sphinx running and the sphinx.yml in config is correct:(I believe)

```
bin_path: /usr/bin/searchd
  searchd_binary_name: searchd
  indexer_binary_name: sphinx-indexer
```

Sphinx seems to be running, as when it is running ( by running command: service searchd start)

The error I get when I browse to a page that uses search is:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError in Jobs#index
 Showing app/views/jobs/index.html.erb where line #30 raised:
 unknown local index 'job_core' in search request
```

Rather than a connection error?
Probably a multitude of problems here but i"m stuck.
Alternatively, I could rewrite the code I'm amending to use a different search function, if so, what's best?

Answer (score 1):

`bin_path` should not include the actual binary names (as you're setting them with `searchd_binary_name` and `indexer_binary_name`) - so try it with just `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Tried that with no luck. No idea what's wrong with the setup but I'm reluctantly going to use conditions on my mysql statements with %like% conditions.

Comment: Tom, if you want to try this again - you have indexed your data before starting the daemon, yes? `rake ts:index`

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your sphinx.yml config to mine, it looks like my values for bin_path, search_binary_name and index_binary_name are expressed as strings, but that doesn't seem to matter. My indexer binary however is ***indexer*** rather than ***sphinx-indexer***

```
development:
    min_infix_len: 3
    config_file: "./config/development.sphinx.conf"
    searchd_log_file: "./log/searchd.log"
    query_log_file: "./log/searchd.query.log"
    pid_file: "./log/searchd.development.pid"
    bin_path: "/usr/local/bin"
    searchd_binary_name: "searchd"
    indexer_binary_name: "indexer"
```

So it maybe worth just checking you've specified the correct binary names. This is in addition to what Pat said re not including the search binary name in the bin_path.